# Cc1plus out of memory error when compiling pcl on RasPi3

Tags: data-visualization, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, makefile

I am trying to compile PCL library on a RasPi3 but every time it fails at 64% when working on pcl_recognition.dir/src/cg/geometric_consistency.cpp.The
error "cc1plus: out of memory allocating 4456508 bytes after a total of 46592000 bytes" is displayed

I have checked my memory and at the point of error I still have 1 GB freeso I cannot understand why this is happening.

The reason I am compiling PCL is because I need to use the library's visualisation command line tools to produce pictures of point clouds from PCD or other data files - no other processing or transformation is required. Given my limited experience with C++ one way forward would be to skip the recognition module (provided no resolution to the problem is found) but in such a case pcl tools is also automatically disabled from the makefile. Is there a way to either force compilation of specific tools e.g pcd2png or compile them after the main build is finished?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just letting you know that I managed to compile the whole thing by removing all the references of the particular module from the tools CMakelists file - removed it from the dependencies list and also removed the executables that depended on it. This allowed the executables in the tools module to be compiled.

If anyone has an insight on the causes of the error message please share

Thanks